# Validate my Sqlite Query?

Tags: sqlite

I have a table in Sqlite with these fields:- Number,Value_Pressed,Time,Date, Month,Year

The Output should be Date,Yes,No and Mood.My query returns almost appropriate result but the problem is how can get the total Value pressed on the particular date.
Here's the query m using:-

"select date,year,month, count(*) Yes from value_table where date between 25 and 30 and value_pressed ='YES' group by date".

25 and 30 is date which is in NSstring.

The output of this query is :
[image]

i have already used the Union.But it's not returning desired output.Please help me.J

Please help me ...I shall be realy  thankful to you for this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you are asking, but if you want a total value, then you should use the SUM function rather than the COUNT function:

```
SELECT date, year, month, SUM(Value_Pressed) AS Yes 
  FROM value_table 
 WHERE date BETWEEN 25 AND 30 
   AND value_pressed ='YES' 
GROUP BY date
```